# How to traffic route to a lightsail intance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have this requirement as below:

1. I have a hosted zone named `ef.com.au`
2. I have a static website hosted on AWS `S3` using CloudFront (https://ef.com.au)
3. Configured the hosted zone to to route traffic to CloudFront

Everything is working fine, and here comes the problematic part.

4. I spinned up a `lightsail` instance with `wordpress` on it.
5. Now I need to route the traffic to this lightsail instancw when I hit `https://ef.com.au/blogs`. Read carefully this is not a sub domain, there is a `/blogs` at the end of the domain `ef.com.au`

How can I achieve this so;

a) When I hit https://ef.com.au - It goes to the website in the `s3` ---> working okay

b) how to traffic route to wordpress `lightsail` instance when I hit `https://ef.com.au/blogs`

I have been researching on this multiple times and couldn't find an answe, **Can someone please tell me how can I do this?**

What configurations should I do, and where should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround but you have to do few changes. like we do in nginx reverse proxy we cannot do this.

- You have to add another origin which is your blog domain. example "blog.ef.com.au" something like that.
- Then create a behavior for the blog origin which you added above. and set the path pattern as /blog/. so any request hitting the url https://ef.com.au/blog will go to https://blog.ef.com.au/blog
- Then in the blog server write a rule to drop the "/blogs/" in the end of the uri since its not nice to serve with 2 "blog" in the url.
- I have tested this and working

set this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blogs/
RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ https://blog.ef.com.au/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to specify a different A record in your host file that points to the IP for the lightsail. EG:-       A 10.0.0.4 blog.ef.com.au

[Route53 Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZndU.jpg)

2. Then you need to create a new origin like following.

[Origin Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6180m.jpg)

3. Then you need to write the behavior rule

[Behavior Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6W1L.jpg)

4. Then you need to write rewrite rule in the .htaccess as given by @arshadzackeriya , It is not needed precisely if it is the only instance you need to run and you are using default server configuration.

Comment: I am using `bitnami` apache 2 in the lightsail for wordpress. When changing `.htaccess` under `opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` doesn't do any changed. Any idea where I should set this in?

Comment: If you are following above , and you will only have one server and it is the default server, you will mostly do not need to configure anything. The server will automatically resolve the path for all addresses from the root level. 

Aka, /blog is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For Bitnami you have to add in

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf
```

as

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blogs/
    RewriteRule ^blogs/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [L,NC,R=301]
</Directory>
```

tested and its working for bitnami